# Программное закрытие приложения

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется `MainActivity`, из которого вызывается `SecondActivity` и уже в нем есть кнопочка на закрытие всего приложения. Пробовал `onFinish()`, но он только текущее (`SecondActivity`) активити закрывает. Также пробовал из `SecondActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
finish();
```

Но и тут только текущее активити закрывает. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

Comment: Можно попробовать в вызываемом активити при помощи setResult() отправить какой-либо код (и завершить при помощи finish()), а в основном активити поймать его в onActivityResult и завершить уже основное активити. Но тогда, скорее всего промелькнет анимация и пользователь увидит переход из вызываемого активити в основное, а потом уже выход. А вообще, советую почитать про Task и Back Stack, а также про жизненный цикл активити. Крайне полезно знать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задав вопрос тут, решил покопаться на англоязычном [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) и нашел очень хорошее решение вопроса:

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Правда тут приложение скорее сворачивается, чем закрывается, но, впринципе, тоже подходит.

Answer (score 1):

`System.exit(0)` Гарантированно закроет приложение

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
this.finishAffinity();
```